# Multiple Files handling with Codependency - Python

Tags: python, module, dependencies

I just finished the tutorial for making a rogue-like-game and I'm on my way to implement freatures.

The problem is, the whole game is a single file with 1k+ lines.

As you can see:

http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod,_part_13_code

I want to divide it in different files/folders to handle the implements better.Maybe a file for each aspect of the game like map/player/npcs/items... but at least divide in Classes/Functions/Main.

The problem is, when I put this in the Main.py:

```
from Classes import *
from Functions import *
```

I get

```
NameError: name 'libtcod' is not defined
```

Which is a Module used in Main.
Then I tried to import the Main.py in the Classes.py and Functions.py

And get the

```
NameError: global name 'MAP_WIDTH' is not defined
```

MAP_WIDTH is a global variable in Main.py

I also tried to import the whole Main.py in Classes.py and Functions.py

But I get:

```
NameError: name 'Fighter' is not defined
```

Fighter is a Class inside Classes.py

Can anyone help me sort this out so I can start implement freatures.

EDIT: One simple example is:

Main.py

```
from Functions import *
def plus_one(ab):
    return ab +1

a = 1
b = 2
c = add_things()
print plus_one(c)
```

Functions.py

```
from Main import *
def add_things():
    global a,b
    return a + b
```

It's a simple example, but in the project it get a lot of mutual dependecy between classes/functions and the main file.

Comment: If you are using libtcod in Classes.py or Functions.py then you will need to import it into those modules, just as you currently import it into Main.py.

Comment: I did, i'm getting NameError for a class.

Comment: My suggestion is that you read a book / do a tutorial on object oriented programming with Python. For instance, Beginning Python: From Novice to Professional by Magnus Lie Hetland is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code and your planned program architecture. Please read my comment on your post. You need to shore up your knowledge of object oriented programming.

First, it is highly recommended to never use `from Classes import *`. You should use `import Classes`. Then to access functions or constants from the module you would use Classes.function_name or Classes.constant. See for more info on how to properly import in Python: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Second, global variables are not recommended in Python. But if you do need them, you need to remember that in python a `global variable` means global to a module, not your entire program. Global variables in Python are a strange beast. If you need to read a global variable nothing special is required. However if you want to modify a global variable from within a function, then you must use the `global` keyword.

Thirdly, what you are doing is called a circle dependancy. Module A, imports Module B and Module B imports Module A. You can define shared functions, classes etc. in a third Module C. Then both A and B can import Module C. You can also defined your constants like `MAP_WIDTH` in module C and access them from A or B with `C.MAP_WIDTH` provided you have an `import C`.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the info... I'm still pretty new to Python and programming in general.

The code I provided isn't mine, it's from the tutorial. I wouldn't use this many globals as have I already been informed that it's not advised.

I was think about making a forth file to save all globals there to access from the others 3?

I'll check the book you mentioned.